# Sorting in MapReduce Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, mapr

I have few basic questions in Hadoop MapReduce.

1. Assume if 100 mappers were executed and zero reducer. Will it
   generate 100 files? All individual are sorted? Across all mapper
   output are sorted?
2. Input for reducer is Key -> Values. For each key, all values are sorted?
3. Assume if 50 reducers were executed. Will it generate 50 files? All individual files are sorted? Across all reducer output are sorted?

Is there any place where guaranteed sorting happens in MapReduce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1.Assume if 100 mappers were executed and zero reducer. Will it generate 100 files?

Yes.

> All individual are sorted?

No. If no reducers are used, then the output of mappers are not sorted. Sorting only takes place when there is a reduce phase.

> Across all mapper output are sorted?

No, for the same reason, as above.

> 2.Input for reducer is Key -> Values. For each key, all values are sorted?

No. However, the keys are sorted. After the shuffling phase, in which the reducer gets the output of the mappers, it merge-sorts the sorted output keys of the mappers (since there IS a reduce phase) and when it starts reducing, the keys are sorted.

> 3.Assume if 50 reducers were executed. Will it generate 50 files?

Yes. (unless you use [MultipleOutputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html))

> All individual files are sorted?

No. The sorted input does not guarantee a sorted output. The output depends on the algorithm that you use in the reduce method.

> Across all reducer output are sorted?

No, for the same reason as above. However, if you use an Identity Reducer, i.e., you just write the input of the reducer as you get it, the reducer's output will be sorted PER REDUCER, not globally.

> Is there any place where guaranteed sorting happens in MapReduce?

Sorting takes place when there is a reduce phase and it is applied in the output keys of each mapper and the input keys of each reducer. If you want to globally sort the input of the reducer, you can either use a single reducer, or a [TotalOrderPartitioner](https://pipiper.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/sorting-using-hadoop-totalorderpartitioner/), which is a bit tricky...

Comment: Looks like this one is not happening.
"Input for reducer is Key -> Values. For each key, all values are sorted?".
For a key, all values are not sorted.

Comment: My bad! Sorting is on the keys, not the values. I will fix it now. Sorry for that!

Comment: @vefthym According to your answer, If we use of just one reducer we will get globally sort of data? That means we get a sort of key in output?

Comment: @SaeedRahmani correct, if you just print the input pairs of the single reducer (i.e., if you use a single IdentityReducer), then the keys will be globally sorted.

Comment: @vefthym http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641984/hadoop-globally-sort-mean-and-when-is-happen-in-mapreduce, This is my question, I using of single reducer but the output is not globally sorted. Why?

Comment: @vefthym What about hadoop-streaming?