# Hadoop - Globally sort mean and when is happen in MapReduce

Tags: sorting, mapreduce, hadoop2, reduce, hadoop-streaming

I am using **Hadoop streaming JAR** for **WordCount**, I want to know how can I get ***Globally Sort***, according to answer on another question in SO, I found that when we use of **just one reducer** we can get Globally sort but in my result with `numReduceTasks=1` (one reducer) it is not sort.

**For example, my input to mapper is:**

> file 1: A long time ago in a galaxy far far away
>
> file 2: Another episode for Star Wars

**Result is:**

> A 1
>
> a 1
>
> Star  1
>
> ago   1
>
> for   1
>
> far   2
>
> away  1
>
> time  1
>
> Wars  1
>
> long  1
>
> Another   1
>
> in    1
>
> episode   1
>
> galaxy    1

**But this is no a Globally Sort!**

So, What is meaning of Sort in **Shuffle and Sort** and **Globally Sort**?

**mapper code:**

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys
    for line in sys.stdin:  
    line = line.strip()    
    words = line.split()    
    for word in words:
        print '%s\t%s' % (word, 1)
```

**reducer code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
 
word2count = {} 

for line in sys.stdin:
   
    line = line.strip()
 
    word, count = line.split('\t', 1)

    try:
        count = int(count)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    try:
        word2count[word] = word2count[word]+count
    except:
        word2count[word] = count

for word in word2count.keys():
    print '%s\t%s'% ( word, word2count[word] )
```

I use this command to run it:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-input /user/cloudera/input \
-output /user/cloudera/output_new_0 \
-mapper /home/cloudera/wordcount_mapper.py \
-reducer /home/cloudera/wordcount_reducer.py \
-numReduceTasks=1
```

Comment: @vefthym I edit my question. But I don't have understand of your mean of the Driver only!